# Xamarin Forms: Report an Issue - Screenshot and Email

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms 5.0, I need to do "Report an Issue" feature in my app.
For this, I need to take screenshot of the current screen, and send email to the developer.

Is this functionality is readily available ?

Or I have to write code...

- to take screenshot
- save the screenshot and
- send to the developer.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/screenshot

Comment: I think there is not an out of the box solution for "Report an Issue", because it depends on the info that you need/require from your user. Maybe you want logs, or images, or the user has to fill a form. If there is a Crash, you could always use analytics like AppCenter

Comment: what do you mean by "issue", is it a bug, a crash, a feature not working as expected?

Comment: Here is how I do it in my apps: https://montemagno.com/how-to-add-support-email-xamarin-apps/ just use the screenshot feaure from Xamarin.Essentials.

Comment: @JamesMontemagno Thank you very much. This is the same I was looking for. I will check ```Xamarin.Essentials``` to take the screen shot.